# Custom View Calendar (TableLayout) is extremely slow

Tags: java, android

I have created a Calendar Custom View from scratch. The reason I don't use the `CalendarView` is that I want to customize it myself. I need a few functions that the `CalendarView` doesn't have. So I built a CustomView:

calendar.xml:

```
<merge
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:id="@+id/calender">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calender_text_view_month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/calender_button_next_month"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/calender_button_next_month"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp"
    />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/calender_button_next_month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_colorprimary_36dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/calender_button_prev_month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_before_colorprimary_36dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
    />
    <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/calender_table_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/calender_text_view_month"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:divider="@drawable/recyclerview_divider"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            android:background="@drawable/table_stroke_color_primary"
    />

</merge>
```

Calendar.java: (Here I have deleted a few methods that are not important, like `getDaysOfMonth`. This is just a little bit of math)

```
public class Calender extends ConstraintLayout {

    private TextView tvMonth;
    private TableLayout calender;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private Calendar c;

    private int selectedDay = -1;
    private int selectedMonth = -1;
    private int selectedYear = -1;

    private Context context;

    public Calender(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public Calender(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public Calender(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        this.context = context;

        LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        l.inflate(R.layout.calender, this, true);

        tvMonth = findViewById(R.id.calender_text_view_month);
        calender = findViewById(R.id.calender_table_layout);

        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        makeCalender();
    }

    private void makeCalender() {
        ArrayList<TableRow> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        tvMonth.setText(String.format("%s %s", month, year));
        calender.removeAllViews();
        calender.addView(createCalenderHeader());
        int dayOfWeek = getFirstDayOfCurrentMonth();
        int daysOfMonth = getDaysOfMonth(month, year);
        int daysPrevMonth = month > 0 ? getDaysOfMonth(month - 1, year) : getDaysOfMonth(11, year - 1);
        int prevMonth = month > 0 ? month - 1 : 11;
        int prevYear = month > 0 ? year : year - 1;
        TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(context);
        tr1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr1.setShowDividers(TableRow.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
        tr1.setDividerDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.table_row_divider));
        for (int day = 1; day <= dayOfWeek; day++) {
            tr1.addView(createCalenderItemPrev(daysPrevMonth + day - dayOfWeek, prevMonth, prevYear));
        }

        for (int day = 1; day <= daysOfMonth; day++) {
            if((dayOfWeek + day) <= 7) {
                tr1.addView(createCalenderItem(day, month, year));
                if(dayOfWeek + day == 7)
                    calender.addView(tr1);
                continue;
            }
            if (rows.size() == 0 ||rows.get(rows.size() - 1).getChildCount() == 7) {
                rows.add(new TableRow(context));

                rows.get(rows.size() - 1).setShowDividers(TableRow.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
                rows.get(rows.size() - 1).setDividerDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.table_row_divider));
                rows.get(rows.size() - 1).setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
            rows.get(rows.size() - 1).addView(createCalenderItem(day, month, year));
        }
        c.set(year, month, daysOfMonth);
        int lastDayOfMonth = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if(lastDayOfMonth != 1) {
            int nextMonth = month < 11 ? month + 1 : 0;
            int nextYear = month < 11 ? year : year + 1;
            for (int i = lastDayOfMonth; i <= 7; i++) {
                rows.get(rows.size() - 1).addView(createCalenderItemPrev(i - lastDayOfMonth + 1, nextMonth, nextYear));
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            calender.addView(rows.get(i));
        }
    }

    private CalenderItem createCalenderItem(int day, int month, int year) {
        CalenderItem item = new CalenderItem(context);
        item.setDate(day, month, year);
        item.setOnItemClickedListener(new CalenderItem.IItemClicked() {
            @Override
            public void itemClicked(int day, int month, int year) {
                selectedDay = day;
                selectedMonth = month;
                selectedYear = year;
                makeCalender();
            }
        });
        return item;
    }

    private CalenderItem createCalenderItemPrev(int day, int month, int year) {
        CalenderItem item = new CalenderItem(context);
        item.setDate(day, month, year);

        return item;
    }
}
```

calendar_item.xml:

```
<merge
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_calender_item_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textAlignment="center"
    />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_calender_item_routine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_view_calender_item_date"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textAlignment="center"
    />

</merge>
```

CalendarItem.java: (Again, I deleted the parts that are not important)

```
public class CalenderItem extends ConstraintLayout {

    private final TextView tvDate;
    private final TextView tvRoutine;

    private IItemClicked listener = null;
    public void setOnItemClickedListener(IItemClicked listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public CalenderItem(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CalenderItem(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CalenderItem(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        l.inflate(R.layout.calender_item, this, true);
        tvDate = findViewById(R.id.text_view_calender_item_date);
        tvRoutine = findViewById(R.id.text_view_calender_item_routine);
        setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_calender_item);
        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener != null) {
                    listener.itemClicked(day, month, year);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public interface IItemClicked {
        void itemClicked(int day, int month, int year);
    }
}
```

This Calendar Custom View works. Every Item is where it should be. But the thing is that it takes extremely long to build, up to a second or two. Everytime I open the fragment with the calendar, the app freezes for one or two seconds. I can't explain why this is.

I can edit the implementation or some other code if you want. But I think that is everything what's important.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your custom `CalendarView` by using `RecyclerView` instead of `TableView`. And using `RecyclerView` will give you more ability to customize date cells (select/deselect, select range, etc.) , support scrolling, swipe, etc.

Or you can use [this library](https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView), which provide highly customizable `CalendarView`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I will answer the question myself, because I managed to solve the issue. It is so slow, because is is rendering more then 30 `CalenderItem`s everytime, which contain of a `LinearLayout` and two `TextView`s. I changed this to just one `TextView` with an "\n" to make it look like two `TextView`s. So I could also remove the Layout and just extend `TextView` Class. So now, it has to render more than 30 `TextView`s and Layouts less then before, which makes it way faster.